# Write a^2k =0 for k in natural numbers

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How do I write $a^{2k}=0$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ as an initiation to a problem simplification? I tried writing `{k,0,N}` as a part of code, which is not detected

Answer (score 1):

Because the keyword simplification is used:

```
Solve[a^(2 k) == 0 && k > 0 && Element[k, Integers], a, Complexes]

{{a -> ConditionalExpression[0, Element[k,Integers] && k >= 1]}}
```

or enter

```
a=ConditionalExpression[0, Element[k,Integers] && k >= 1]
```

The potentiation is not needed until explicitly required.

Refine and Simplify:

```
Refine[a^(2 k) == 0, Assumptions -> Element[k, Integers] && k >= 0]
Simplify[a^(2 k) == 0, Assumptions -> Element[k, Integers] && k >= 0]
```

work only with this if a valid simplification is achieved.

But simplification is not really meant probably.

`a^2k` is a special kind polynomial called monomial. That can be treated with a different set of built-ins.

```
PolynomialMod[3 a^(2 k) + 2 a^(2 k)^2 + 1, a^(2 k)]
```

(*

ConditionalExpression[1 + 3 0^(2 k) + 2 0^(4 k),
[Element[k, Integers] && k >= 1]

*)

where the ConditionalExpression is transformed. Or alike.

```
FullSimplify@%
```

(* `ConditionalExpression[1, Element[k,Integers] && k >= 1`]  *)